# Apache reverse proxy for several Jenkins CI and Nexus Maven repositories

Tags: apache2, jenkins, apache, reverse-proxy, nexus

I am trying to setup a front-end (reverse proxy) for several Nexus and Jenkins CI servers using Apache httpd and need some help. We have URLs like-

> abc.internal.net:8080/
>
> def.internal.net:9000/jenkins/
>
> ghi.internal.net:8080/jenkins/
>
> jkl.internal.net:8081/nexus/
>
> foo.internal.net/nexus/

I would like each of these to be setup behind the FE reverse proxy so as to have something like-

> scm.internal.net/abc-jenkins/
>
> scm.internal.net/def-jenkins/
>
> scm.internal.net/ghi-jenkins/
>
> scm.internal.net/jkl-nexus/
>
> scm.internal.net/foo-nexus/

Some of the services use root context. Could these be forced into arbitrary web context?

I have very limited knowledge of Apache httpd so some real configs would help immensely. Most of these services need URL, content and CSS fixing in the response. If this could be done without changing the existing web context on the severs that these services are running, that would be awesome.

Also, I need soft landing on these changes so legacy URL continue to work for few weeks as developers and automation transition to the new scheme. Is this asking for too much?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ProxyPassMatch`, you can try:

```
ProxyPassMatch /([^-]+)-(.*)$ http://$1.internal.net:9000/$2
```

But that only accounts for ones running not as root and on port 9000. Since the root and the port seem to be completely arbitrary, you'll probably just need to enumerate through each one:

```
ProxyPass /abc-jenkins/ http://abc.internal.net:8080/
ProxyPassReverse /abc-jenkins/ http://abc.internal.net:8080/

ProxyPass /def-jenkins/ http://def.internal.net:9000/jenkins/
ProxyPassReverse /def-jenkins/ http://def.internal.net:9000/jenkins/

ProxyPass /ghi-jenkins/ http://ghi.internal.net:8080/jenkins/
ProxyPassReverse /ghi-jenkins/ http://ghi.internal.net:8080/jenkins/

ProxyPass /jkl-nexus/ http://jkl.internal.net:8081/nexus/
ProxyPassReverse /jkl-nexus/ http://jkl.internal.net:8081/nexus/
```

etc.